# Whats the meaning of "run against the wall" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, idioms

I read this in a story called *A Darker Shade of magic* by V.E. Schwab.  You can read an  extract https://www.tor.com/2015/01/21/a-darker-shade-of-magic-excerpt-v-e-schwab/

> A marble counter **ran against the wall**, and on it a basin of water waited for him, as it always did. He rinsed his bloody hand, as well as the silver crown he’d used for passage, then slipped the cord it hung on over his head, and tucked the coin back beneath his collar. In the hall beyond, he could hear the shuffle of feet, the low murmur of servants and guards.

Whats the meaning of "run against the wall" in this?

Comment: Fateme, _please_ tell us where a sentence comes from when you ask a question about it!

Comment: Fateme, I've edited.  This is the minimum you need in your question.  You must have a source, a link (if possible) and a quote showing the context.  WIthout that your questions will be downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 3):

the verb run is used to describe certain architectural or building features:

- A road runs along the left side of the pasture.

In this sense, which is not so clearly spelled out in some dictionaries, it is the same idea as to extend.

A marble counter has length. Its length runs or extends against a wall.

Comment: The best definition I can find is "to lie or extend in relation to something" ([13 b in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run)), which is pretty much what you say in your last paragraph.

Comment: @StuartF Sure, of course. I believe I said: "extends against a wall" where a wall is the something.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is not totally clear, but this is my best guess.  "A marble counter ran against the wall" means that there was a countertop made of marble (a type of rock) which was built or installed against a wall.